# using applyDecorators and Interceptors

Tags: node.js, typescript, interceptor

I have a applyDecorators that called postCall.
This postCall built from 4 decorators Post,ApiOperation,ApiResponse,UsePipes.
And I have Interceptor that convert to me the property in the request body from camel case to snake case. When I using both of them  the interceptor doesn’t work.
example :

```
    @PostCall(...)
    @UseInterceptors(...)
    function(@Body()...){
    ...
    }
```